# Laravel Spatie Multitenancy with Laravel Queue Worker

Tags: laravel

I have integrated `spatie/laravel-multitenancy` in my Laravel 8 app. My database connection is set by the multitenancy package for each request.

But when I run `php artisan queue:work --queue=user` command, my jobs are not processed and it throws following error

`Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (SQL: select * from jobs where queue = user...)`

So in my understanding, multitenancy package not setting the database connection when request is initiated by queue worker. I don't find any setting in `multitenancy.php` which is related to setting the database connection for background worker.

Is there any package configuration that I am missing?

**multitenancy.php**

```
return [
    'tenant_finder' => Spatie\Multitenancy\TenantFinder\DomainTenantFinder::class,

    'tenant_artisan_search_fields' => [
        'id',
    ],

    'switch_tenant_tasks' => [
        \Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchTenantDatabaseTask::class,
        \App\MultiTenant\SetConfig::class //my custom task
    ],

    'tenant_model' => Tenant::class,

    'queues_are_tenant_aware_by_default' => true,

    'tenant_database_connection_name' => 'tenant',

    'landlord_database_connection_name' => 'landlord',

    'current_tenant_container_key' => 'currentTenant',

    'shared_routes_cache' => false,

    'actions' => [
        'make_tenant_current_action' => MakeTenantCurrentAction::class,
        'forget_current_tenant_action' => ForgetCurrentTenantAction::class,
        'make_queue_tenant_aware_action' => MakeQueueTenantAwareAction::class,
        'migrate_tenant' => MigrateTenantAction::class,
    ],

    'queueable_to_job' => [
        SendQueuedMailable::class => 'mailable',
        SendQueuedNotifications::class => 'notification',
        CallQueuedListener::class => 'class',
        BroadcastEvent::class => 'event',
    ],
];
```